# ion slider not working in ModalController ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Version:
Cordova: cordova-lib@8.1.1
Ionic: 6.10.1

Error : `this.slider.update is not a function`

in .ts

```
import { ModalController, IonSlides } from "@ionic/angular";

 trainingSliderOpts = {
speed: 400,
initialSlide: 0,
preloadImages: true,
allowTouchMove: false,
 };
result: any;
@ViewChild("trainingSlider", { static: true }) slider: IonSlides;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
this.slider.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a .then function at the end like that:

```
this.ionSlides.update().then(() =>
        console.log('updated'))
    }
```

**If not working try the following on top of your your class:**

```
 @ViewChild('slider', {read: ElementRef})slider: ElementRef;
```

and then call it like this:

```
this.slider.nativeElement.update();
```

Comment: this is not working r: this.slider.update is not a function
    at

Comment: 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-slide'. but getting this issue for ngForOF any idea abt this?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, do you want to use *ngFor ?

Comment: Yes after changing with nativeElelment ngFor is not worling